# Track Promotional Code Sales

Tags: tracking

Is there a way I can track actual sales on purchases utilizing Promo or Discount Codes obtained through my site?  My site will link to e-commerce sites where users can use those promo codes on their purchases to save money.  My site will not actually be selling any items, it is all referrals to other sites.  I want this to be done outside of any 3rd party commission platform such as Commission Junction or LinkShare.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you planning to program something based on this, or should it be on Webmasters?

Comment: I'm open to any solution that makes sense and is accurate.

Comment: I think you're going to have to talk to those e-commerce sites as that's where the sales are made.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a couple of possibilities:

1. Does the site have any sort of payment notification system? For example, PayPal can send your server an automatic notification whenever a payment is received. If the service you are using has something similar it may contain any promo code that is used.
2. You can track outbound clicks to these sites, however that doesn't guarantee a sale was made. If the user clicked the link, but didn't make a purchase, it wouldn't be recorded properly.

I think it is difficult to achieve what you are trying to do accurately unless a method is provided by the site you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop a tracking pixel and ask your partner site to place it in conversion completion page and ask them to pass the used promo code value.

Regarding creating tracking pixel, [read this discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079666/developing-a-tracking-pixel)